# Tomcat 404 when using servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

So I am currently trying to test a project whose facets I have changed, namely, I added a dynamic web component to it. In order to do so I decided to do a basic html form, and associated servlet with it.

However, when I try to run it I get a 404. Interestingly enough, a project I had which worked fine today is now also facing a similar issue. Though my practice servlet, which is used a template for everything else, does not have this issue.

the form follows this format:

```
<form action="myServlet">
<input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

the servlet simply returns a `writer.println("Hello World");`

Error message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /userName/LoginServlet

type Status report

message /userName/LoginServlet

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
```

Edit, and now the one servlet that worked also stopped working throwing the same error. If it helps, I am trying to run it from eclipse, by right clicking on my html page and then selecting for it to run on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was rather simple to hidden, since the name was refactored, the servlet mapping in eclipse did not show this. Deleting and recreating the servlet fixed it.

At least for now.